# How to connect Django to MongoDB database?

Tags: python, django, mongodb, database

I want to start new project to help students. And I planned to use Python( Django framework ) for backend and mysql for database. Nowadays I researched about NoSQL databases and found MongoDB. However I searched about Django support for MongoDB seems like it is not supported officially. So, how can I use MongoDB with Django ?

Comment: https://django-mongodb-engine.readthedocs.org/en/latest/

Comment: Have you considered using a [Django to MongoDB connector](https://nesdis.github.io/djongo/) like Djongo

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use MongoEngine which is a ODM (Object Document Mapper) for Python. It supports Django Auth, Sessions and other nice stuff.

http://docs.mongoengine.org/en/latest/

However you can not use the Django Admin with MongoDB althought there are projects trying to reach this, none of them is totally stable

Comment: the above link is not working, try this : https://mongoengine-odm.readthedocs.io/index.html

Answer (score 2):

Django 1.5 supports Mongodb for installing and configuring it please follow the following link 
https://django-mongodb-engine.readthedocs.org/en/latest/topics/setup.html.

It provides a customised django 1.5 which helps in working with mongodb